# Issue with cordova plugin to set wallpaper with auto link

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I'm using [cordova-plugin-wallpaper](https://github.com/fbsanches/cordova-plugin-wallpaper) which works fine if i hardcode image like this.

```
window.plugins.wallpaper.setImage("images/1462204239933.jpg");
```

but if i try to get image link with jquery from active slide, it won't set wallpaper with android app. This is what i tried.

```
var picture = $$(".swiper-slide-active").find(".pic").attr('src');
window.plugins.wallpaper.setImage('"'+picture+'"');
```

I checked console.log and it's getting image src fine for each slide. Any suggestion how to work around this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was strings around variable `('"'+picture+'"')` which were causing the issue. Removing that fixed the issue. Thanks to "flyingP0tat0" for pointing this on github issue.

Here is the full code if anyone need.

HTML

```
<div class="page-content">
           <button class="setwp floating-button"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i></button>
          <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/001.jpg" rel="1"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/002.jpg" rel="2"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/003.jpg" rel="3"></div>
                </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function wp() {
    var wppic = $$(".swiper-slide-active").find("img").attr('src');
    window.plugins.wallpaper.setImage(wppic);
}
function wpalert() {
    alert('Wallpaper is set');
}
$$('.setwp').on('click', function (e) {
     wp(); wpalert();
});
```